# How to find out of these two vectors are a basis of R^2

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is $\begin{bmatrix}-4\\6\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-3\end{bmatrix}$ a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$

How exactly can I find out if these are a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$. From my understanding a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) is if the vectors are linearly independent and every vector in the vector space is a linear combination of this set. In more general terms, a basis is a linearly independent spanning set. Should I start by combining the vectors and putting them in [RREF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)?

Answer (score 1):

$-2(2,-3)=(-4,6)$ so it is not  a base.

Comment: So this set of vectors is linearly dependent because they are multiples of each other correct?

Comment: yes that's correct @Yusha